# Creating Kubernetes cluster nodes using Rancher UI

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, etcd, kubernetes-cluster, on-premises-instances

I'm trying to create a kubernetes cluster with 1 or 3 nodes(on 1 or 3 VMs) using "Rancher UI".

What things should I install on the VMs before attempting to create cluster with Rancher UI? (except docker which I've installed)

**I'm so confused** and there are many many docs and stuff about installing k8s, k3s, helm, rke and etc..